# What is wrong with my link_to tag? NameError. undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a blog with the rails 4 quickly tutorial by Bala Paranj on p.140 it says to use the following code (Note: the book is a rails 4 tutorial and I am using rails 5).

```
<%= link_to "Delete Comment" , article_comment(article, comment),
method: :delete %>
```

This code is for a link to delete the comment associated with an article on the blog. The link never appears because when the article page is loaded i get the following error.

```
NameError in Articles#show

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `article' for #<#<Class:0x56b9e90>:0xa1d44a0>):
    17:   </p>
    18: <% end %>
    19:
    20: <%= link_to "Delete Comment" , article_comment(article, comment),
    21: method: :delete %>
    22:
    23: <h2>Add a comment:</h2>
```

so as I understand it is saying that it doesnt have access to the variable "article". However I have defined this in my controller.

from articles.controller.rb:

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path, notice: "Delete success"
  end
```

so why is the view not recognizing the variable "article" when it is clearly defined in the controller for the view to have access to it?

EDIT show action was as follows

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
```

EDIT 2 routes file as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'welcome/index'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'welcome#index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Edit 3: rake routes

```
article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                     POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                     PATCH  /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     PUT    /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                     DELETE /articles/:article_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
```

Edit 4(a): show.html.erb file

```
<p>
<%= @article.title %><br>
</p>
<p>
<%= @article.description %><br>
</p>

<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.description %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Delete Comment" , article_comment(article, comment),
method: :delete %>

<h2>Add a comment:</h2>
<%= form_for([@article, @article.comments.build]) do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :commenter %><br />
<%= f.text_field :commenter %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.label :description %><br />
<%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Edit 4(b) articles controller file

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.all
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    Article.create(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description))
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    permitted_columns = params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
    @article.update_attributes(permitted_columns)
    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    redirect_to articles_path, notice: "Delete success"
  end

end
```

Edit 4(c) comments controller file

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    permitted_columns = params[:comment].permit(:commenter, :description)
    @comment = @article.comments.create(permitted_columns)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end

end
```

Comment: When you are using article_comment for the links path, are you assigning that in an iteration of the articles comment like @article.comments.each do |article_comment|? If so, there is no need to pass parameters to the path since delete method uses the route DELETE comments/:id generated by resources. Same way GET comments/:id will point to comments#show. That is unless you didn't add resources :comments to route.rb.

Comment: routes file added above. i added resources comments.

Comment: Added an answer. Try it and let us know what you get. There may be one more step past it to do but it should get you closer to what you are after.

Comment: could you explain what you meant by "assigning that in an iteration of the articles comment"?

Comment: so am finally seeing what you are trying to do...hard to read on a mobile phone. you are trying to add a delete link to a show page for each comment associated with a specific article. you are assigning the article to an instance variable (@article) and probably running it through a loop like '@article.comments.each do |article_comment|'. This list every comment associated with the article. each of which have a delete link. am i right so far?

Comment: if its not too much trouble, can you show more text from your show.html.erb. i suspect there is a missing piece of the puzzle in that text.

Comment: yes that's spot on, the linkto tag is the delete option for each comment on the blog. i will post the whole show.html.erb in an edit above.

Comment: I see one issue. You destroy link is out side your comments loop so it doesn't understand what comment you are trying to destroy. I'll edit my answer to reflect what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a shallow option to your resources :articles. This will give you more direct routes to your comments along with routes for comments of articles.

```
resources :articles, shallow: true do
  resources :comments
end
```

EDIT>>>

when you add the shallow option you get these routes...

```
   article_comments GET    /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)     comments#index
                    POST   /articles/:article_id/comments(.:format)     comments#create
new_article_comment GET    /articles/:article_id/comments/new(.:format) comments#new
       edit_comment GET    /comments/:id/edit(.:format)                 comments#edit
            comment GET    /comments/:id(.:format)                      comments#show
                    PATCH  /comments/:id(.:format)                      comments#update
                    PUT    /comments/:id(.:format)                      comments#update
                    DELETE /comments/:id(.:format)                      comments#destroy
           articles GET    /articles(.:format)                          articles#index
                    POST   /articles(.:format)                          articles#create
        new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)                      articles#new
       edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)                 articles#edit
            article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                      articles#show
                    PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                      articles#update
                    PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                      articles#update
                    DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                      articles#destroy
```

Make sure that you put the destroy link inside the loop. Here is your code...

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.description %>
  </p>
<% end %>

# the link is outside the loop so the comment variable is not declared.
# once the program leaves the loop, the variable loses all declaration.
# also, you are using a local variable for article. in your show method.
# you are assigning an instance variable @article. the local variable is
# not declared so you will get an "I don't know what this variable is."
# error...same as the comment outside of the loop.

<%= link_to "Delete Comment" , article_comment(article, comment), method: :delete %>
```

it should look like this. note that the link is inside the loop and the link only uses the comment as the path to destroy the comment and not a regular path...

```
<h2>Comments</h2>
<% @article.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p>
    <strong>Commenter:</strong>
    <%= comment.commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <strong>Comment:</strong>
    <%= comment.description %>
  </p>
  # putting the link inside the loop creates a delete link for each comment
  # that is listed by the loop. the correct path for delete of any item is 
  # comment/1 with a delete method so called the comment directly vs using 
  # params is better. unless you prefer not to use the shallow method. ill 
  # add a reference at the bottom to use instead for that case.
  <%= link_to "Delete Comment" , comment, method: :delete %>
<% end %>
```

of course, this will direct you to the comments controller and not the articles controller. you will probably want to add a redirect back to the article you were using so be sure to add the following to your destroy method...

EDIT>>> I put the wrong way to redirect in the previous version. updated with correct way to redirect in this instance.

```
def destroy
  # just a quick tip about variables...
  # as you can see you don't have to use instance variables
  # if you are working inside a method. local variables work
  # just fine. you do, however, need instance variables to
  # pass information from one method to another or from a
  # method to a view. i think that is one reason you were getting
  # the error messages in the beginning.

  article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  comment = article.comments.find(params[:id])
  comment.destroy

  # redirects back to articles#show with article.id as id
  redirect_to article
end
```

EDIT>>> for use of nested resource without shallow option...

```
 # you need to add _path to any path listed in rake routes. this is a 
 # helper method in rails that will create the path you are looking for
 # based on your routes config file. then add the params you are needing
 # to send. you were close before but make sure to use the instance
 # variable @article and place the link inside the loop for the variables
 # to work.
 <%= link_to "Delete Comment" , article_comment_path(@article, comment), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: that didn't work. i got the same error.  Can anyone explain why i am getting an undefined variable error for 'article' when 'article' is clearly defined in the controller?  all steps in the tutorial have worked up until now including very similar steps earlier on.

Comment: you are getting an undefined variable because there is a variable that was not declared before you called it. I suspect it is the article in article_commet(article, comment). probably suppose to be the instance variable you assigned in the show method (@article).

Comment: that is what i dont understand. i have just made an edit and included articles controller, comments controller and show.html.erb.  As you will see both variables article and comment are clearly defined, so i cant understand why it says they are undefined.

Comment: i used the option without the use of shallow. both your suggestions were correct. the delete was outside of the loop (which was my mistake), and also article should have been @article (this was a mistake in the tutorial). this step now seems to work. still unsure why article was an instance veriable and not commet, i.e. "@article, comment" not "@article, @comment" or "article, comment". thank you very much for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: I explained local variables and instance variables in my answer. The reason it's comment and not @comment is because the loop is using a local variable (comment) to iterate which item is current in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

make a partial file in both articles and comments views i.e is   _comment.html.erb and write like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy Comment', [comment.article, comment],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

And in articles.controller.rb:

```
def destroy
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 @article.destroy
 redirect_to articles_path
end

render a partial file i.e _comment.html.erb in app/views/articles/show.html.erb like this:

<%= render 'comment' %>
```